# Referencing and changing a material on a meshrenderer in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and my old models (simple cubes with textures/materials on it) was working with this blink code I had. (Mesh gets hit it 'blinks').  Now I had a friend in blender whip up new models and I tweaked my blink code to grab the right materials and blink those.  But the code isn't erroring out yet it is doing nothing either.

It is pretty simple (so I thought) what I am trying to do yet nothing  works.

```
MeshRenderer myRend;
void Start () {
        #store reference for later
        myRend = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
}
```

...later in the collide:

```
myRend.materials[1] = null; //or use another material still shows original material name down below
Debug.Log("Mat change: " + myRend.materials[1].name);
```

It still shows the original name not a null?  so the rest of my code very much doesn't work:
(blink material is just a white material)
(I also know I have the right index selected for materials)

```
IEnumerator CollideFlash()
 {
  case 2:
            myRend.materials[1] = blinkMaterial;
            Debug.Log("Mat change: " + myRend.materials[1].name);

            myRend.materials[1].color = Color.white;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            //change it back from white to this
            myRend.materials[1] = m;
            myRend.materials[1].color = c;
            break;

... ... ..
```

I know the above executes but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First material is materials[0] not material[1], if material[1] is present (and I assume it must be since you are not getting a null pointer error), it may not be the main material you are seeing when changing the materials on MeshRenderer.

You can also try accessing it via meshRenderer.shaderdMaterial.

Also please note that the color modifier is multiplied by albedo texture, so if you are using a texture, setting the color to white will change nothing - its still the same texture, multipliying by black, on the other hand will darken the texture

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20321553)

Comment: I guess you are right, I edited my answer to provide more detailed information

Comment: So I tried ShaderMaterial, same issue.  I do print out to the screen which material name it is, it is the name of the material I want to change.  In the inspector the MeshRenderer under materials has two slots, the second one (so [1]) is the one I want to change.  The bigger take away though is my code above.  I can change it as I set it to my blinkMaterial (fair enough the color does nothing), but printing out the name still prints out the name of the orig material not what I had JUST set it to.  A headscratcher.

Comment: Your color point helped me, it was blinking the color.white was working on my other models because I figured out the albedo color was a grey to begin with on those models with a diff material. So the new models this blinking wasn't working on was white on the material, so I took the white down to grey and now it does flash white (same texture) so a nice subtle effect.    Still replacing the material with my blank white blinkMat does nothing but letting that lie for now.